# change date format from 2017-01-11 to 01/12/2017

Tags: jquery, date, format

I am having dates in this form. Format of both dates is different. i need to compare these dates so if format is not same i cannot get anything.

```
  2017-01-11
  01/12/2017
```

I want to change format of this date 2017-01-11 in to this  01/12/2017.
How can i do that?

I am trying it in this way

```
      var date = $(this).val();
      day  = date.getDate(),  
      month = date.getMonth() + 1,              
      year =  date.getFullYear();

     alert(year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
```

getting error date.getDate is not a function

Comment: Not responding to your question but a little advice: you should read about moment.js for handling your date: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: i want it in jquery

Comment: Not sure about jquery, but in batch/java I would cut the strings at `/` and `-` and then compare the resulting arrays...

Comment: Do you means `2017-01-11` to `01/11/2017`?

Comment: if you can do this then it will be good. i just want the same format to match these dates in if condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
var d = new Date('2017-01-11');
var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
var a = n.split('/');

console.log(a);
if(a[0] <=9)
{
  a[0] = '0'+a[0];
}
if(a[1] <=9)
 {
  a[1] = '0'+a[1];
 }
var date = a.join('/');
alert(date);
```

See fiddle here.http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBH5FASDUQEI

Comment: this will get a current date in its own format. i have a date will given format.

Comment: just pass date that you want to convert.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBH4BLS7CCLS see here. it is working.

Comment: i have checked it.
01/06/2017
1/6/2017
can you please notice the difference? due to this i can't match these two.
can you solve this please.

Comment: you can achieve this using just if/else stmt.

Comment: how? 
i can't understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132479/discussion-between-hikmat-sijapati-and-shahid-hamdam).

Answer (score 0):

There is an awesome library named Moment.js to work with dates in javascript. I've created an [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aminur/qo7cnc7d/) demonstrating how easy and clean your code will be with this library, sample: `alert(moment('2017-01-11').isSame('01/12/2017'));` You don't have to worry about date formats anymore, it will compare two date strings with different formatting. Happy coding :)

Comment: i have dates with same format now and i try to match them its not working.
 if(date == ndate)
         {
    alert("matched");
    console.log("matched");
             $("li.lia").addClass("selectedli");
         }

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? then it'll be easy to identify what's wrong.

Comment: On a second thought, are you using Moment.js library?

Comment: i am using jquery just.

Comment: did you see the jsfiddle link i've attached in my answer?